# How to return to previous page after execute a form in php

Tags: php

this is  my code and the PHP's Header () function  does not help me, can someone help me to find my errors or another solution?
 After execute this query "DELETE  FROM  pagos where id=$id" dont return me to tabla_pagos.php

```
 <?php
         include "app/conexionqa.php";
        require("templates/menu.php");

        $id=$_GET["parametro"];

        $data = $conn -> query("SELECT * FROM pagos where id=$id" );

        if(isset($_POST['eliminar'])){
        $idAdmin=$_POST["idAdmin"];
        $fPago=$_POST["fPago"];
        $status=$_POST["status"];
        $montoPagar=$_POST["montoPagar"];


        $sql= $conn -> query("DELETE  FROM  pagos where id=$id");
        header("Location: tabla_pagos.php");

        }?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


    <body>
        <br>
        <br>

        <section class="header__user">

        <!--<div id="edit" class="modal">-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <h3 class="center unbutu loginTitle blue-text">Eliminar registro</h3>
                    <?php foreach($data as $campo){?>
                <form action="#" method="post">

                    <label>Id</label>
                    <p><?php echo $id; ?></p>
                    <label>Invitado por:</label>
                    <input type="text"   name="idAdmin" value="<?php echo $campo['idAdmin']; ?>"/>
                    <label>Fecha de pago</label>
                    <input type="text"   name="fPago" value="<?php echo $campo['fPago']; ?>"/>
                    <label>Status</label>
                    <input type="text"   name="status" value="<?php echo $campo['status']; ?>"/>
                    <label>Cantidad ultimo pago</label>
                    <input type="text"   name="montoPagar" value="<?php echo $campo['montoPagar']; ?>"/>
                    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="eliminar">Eliminar 
                    </button>
                    <a href="tabla_pagos.php"> Cancelar</a>

                </form>

                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    </body>
    </html>
    <?php require("templates/footer.php"); 

?>
```

Comment: From manual "Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. " So... What's in the included files? http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: So what does happen?

Comment: Hi Andreas! In my include files  i only have conection to database

Comment: @Frida any news? Found the output yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment to Matt's answer it seems as you have output in your file menu.php.

You can not have any output prior to header() function.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

Comment: THAANKS,Thanks a lot, your help was really useful, I removed an unnecessary require and it worked

Comment: Are you sure it's unnecessary? Usually requires are... Required... If my answer was correct you can accept the answer on the left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a call to `exit;` after your `header("Location: tabla_pagos.php");` call in order to stop further page processing.

```
 <?php
        include "app/conexionqa.php";
        require("templates/menu.php");

        $id=$_GET["parametro"];

        $data = $conn -> query("SELECT * FROM pagos where id=$id" );

        if(isset($_POST['eliminar'])){
        $idAdmin=$_POST["idAdmin"];
        $fPago=$_POST["fPago"];
        $status=$_POST["status"];
        $montoPagar=$_POST["montoPagar"];


        $sql= $conn -> query("DELETE  FROM  pagos where id=$id");
        header("Location: tabla_pagos.php");
        exit;    
   }?>
```

The PHP documentation for `header()` shows this in it's example:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

You can see more at http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php.

Comment: Hi Matt Rink!!   I made those changes but it sends me an warning. -Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cimacomu/epokavirtual.com/cimacomunidad/templates/menu.php:26) in /home/cimacomu/epokavirtual.com/cimacomunidad/eliminar.php on line 17

Comment: @Frida that tells you that you have some output before the header, just as I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: Have a close look at your included files. Any whitespace (new lines, spaces or tabs) outside of PHP tags will be considered content and returned.